# Oracle Turing Machine EXP^EXP

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, oracle-machines

I'm reading Arora Barak and in that it is written that when $O \in \mathrm{P}$, then $\mathrm{P}^O = \mathrm{P}$. Can this be generalized?
Intuitively,  I think that $\mathrm{NP}^\mathrm{NP} \neq \mathrm{NP}$ but $\mathrm{EXP}^\mathrm{EXP} = \mathrm{EXP}$.
Am I right? Any elaboration on the same would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, $\mathsf{EXP^{EXP}=2EXP}$, a set of languages decidable in $O\left(2^{2^{\mathrm{poly}(n)}}\right)$ time.

This is just because you can give exponentially long input to an oracle which can solve it. So, the total power is $\exp(\exp(n))\ne \exp(n)$.

To see why $\mathsf P$ is self-low just take a machine that can run quadratic time and give to it the same oracle. While the resulting machine will be able to solve all languages in $\mathsf{DTIME}(n^4)$ it is still polynomial. Generalizing, $\mathrm{poly}(\mathrm{poly}(n))=\mathrm{poly}(n)$.

Was wrong, now understood that this is the only way to make machine that faster. Thanks to Ariel.

P.S. There is a parsimonious exp-time reduction from $\mathsf{2EXP}$-complete problem to an exponentially longer $\mathsf{EXP}$-complete problem.

Comment: Asking exponentially many queries does not necessarily require double exponential power, the problem is that the queries can be exponentially long.

Comment: My logic was an $EXP$ machine can ask $2^{O(n)}$ queries to the oracle, and each oracle would itself solve an exponential time problem in a single step. So the total power would be $2^{O(n)} \times 2^{O(n)}$ which would still be in $EXP$

Comment: So, $EXP^{EXP} = EXP$ is true? I'm sorry I don't get the exponentially long queries part.

Comment: @Gary, you can solve EXP-complete problem of length $2^n$ using the oracle. You can reduce 2EXP-complete problem of length $n$ to an EXP-complete problem of length $2^n$.

Comment: I just got it! Thanks a ton for clearing it out